# Qt5.7.を使っているのですが、DirectXを使うにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか

Tags: qt5

今、Windowsを使っていて、QtでDirectXを使いたかったので、質問させていただきます。
ちなみに、C++で書いてます。

Answer (score 1):

[この記事](http://qiita.com/Chironian/items/acb465f388aa75f5d6a5)が参考にならないでしょうか。(リンク先はQt5.4を使った記事です。5.7の場合、C++11対応のコンパイラが必要らしいです)